# how to call a method using soap in php

Tags: php, soap, wsdl

I have created php file. It contains details about to access (wsdl)xml file and function. I need to call a function with paramaters but i can't able to call a function. In that function i need to print the value of parameters.**$ve = $soap_client->sayHello($b);**--->>>while executing this line am getting error couldnot connect to host(it directly passed to the catch).Anyone plz point me what mistake i did in that code. I passed the value like in the url **"http://xxx.xxx.x.xx/testcode.php?method=sayHello&name=shankar"**
In my php file look like this testcode.php:

```
 <?php
   try
   {
      $soap_client=new SoapClient("HelloWorld.wsdl");
      $a = $_GET["method"];
      $b = $_GET["name"];
      echo $b;
      $ve = $soap_client->sayHello($b);
      function sayHello($b)
      {
          echo 'continue';
          echo $b;
      }
    }
    catch(SoapFault $exception)
    {
       echo $exception->getMessage();
    }
 ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

try set **location** param if not yet exist in wsdl schema:

WSDL mode:

```
$client = new SoapClient('HelloWorld.wsdl', 
                          array(
                                'location' => 'http://xxx.xxx.x.xx/testcode.php',
                          ));
```

Non WSDL mode:

```
$client = new SoapClient(null, array(
      'location' => "http://xxx.xxx.x.xx/testcode.php",
      'uri'      => "urn://etc",
      'trace'    => 1 ));

echo $client->sayHello('foo');
```

server example for non WSDL mode:

```
class Service
{
    public function sayHello($name)
    {
        return 'Hello ' . $name;
    }
}
$server = new SoapServer(null, array('uri' => "urn://etc/"));
$server->setClass("Service");
$server->handle();
```

and similar for wsdl..

also you can use [php-wsdl-creator](https://code.google.com/p/php-wsdl-creator/) for generated new wsdl data

---

**added:**

Full sample for WSDL mode - step by step:

1) Create the simple example service:

```php
class Service
{
    /**
     * @param string $name
     * @return string
     */
    public function sayHello($name)
    {
        return 'Hello ' . $name;
    }
}
$server = new SoapServer('http://example.com/wsdl-gen/'); //our auto-gen. schema
$server->setClass("Service");
$server->handle();
```

2) For new generated schema, I use php-wsdl-creator *(go to the next step if you already have)*

```php
require_once 'php-wsdl/class.phpwsdl.php';

$namespace = 'http://example.com/';
$location  = 'http://example.com/server.php';
$wsdl = PhpWsdl::CreateInstance($namespace, $location, './cache',
    array(
            '../soap-server.php' // all classes for generator
        ),
    null,
    null,
    null,
    false,
    false);

//$wsdl->RunServer(); // bonus :) generated full client with documentation
$wsdl->Optimize = false;
$wsdl = $wsdl->CreateWsdl();
```

3) WSDL-Schema can be:

```
<wsdl:definitions xmlns:tns="http://example.com/" targetNamespace="http://example.com/" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
    <wsdl:message name="sayHelloSoapIn">
        <wsdl:part name="name" type="s:string" />
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:message name="sayHelloSoapOut">
        <wsdl:part name="return" type="s:string" />
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:portType name="ServiceSoap">
        <wsdl:operation name="sayHello">
            <wsdl:input message="tns:sayHelloSoapIn" />
            <wsdl:output message="tns:sayHelloSoapOut" />
        </wsdl:operation>
    </wsdl:portType>
    <wsdl:binding name="ServiceSoap" type="tns:ServiceSoap">
        <soap:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" style="rpc" />
        <wsdl:operation name="sayHello">
            <soap:operation soapAction="http://example.com/sayHello" />
            <wsdl:input>
                <soap:body use="encoded" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" namespace="http://example.com/" parts="name" />
            </wsdl:input>
            <wsdl:output>
                <soap:body use="encoded" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" namespace="http://example.com/" parts="return" />
            </wsdl:output>
        </wsdl:operation>
    </wsdl:binding>
    <wsdl:service name="Service">
        <wsdl:port name="ServiceSoap" binding="tns:ServiceSoap">
            <soap:address location="http://example.com/soap-server.php" />
        </wsdl:port>
    </wsdl:service>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

4) Create example client for current scheme:

```
$client = new SoapClient(
                  'http://example.com/wsdl-gen/', //schema
                   array(
                       'location' => 'http://test/server.php' //SOAP server addr
                       //we provide this option if the location param is not valid in scheme or not exist
                   ));
```

5) That's all, example working with our service methods:

```
$client->sayHello('reg'); //string 'Hello reg' (length=9)
```

Documentation and instruments:

- [PhpWsdl](https://code.google.com/p/php-wsdl-creator/) - WSDL generator for PHP. *(I used this in my job ~2 year ago)*
- - [Documentation](https://code.google.com/p/php-wsdl-creator/wiki/Usage)
- [Web Services - SOAP in PHP](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.soap.php)
- - [SoapClient class](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.soapclient.php)
- - [SoapServer class](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.soapserver.php)

Comment: @PythonTeam If you work in **non-WSDL mode**, the location and uri options must be set, where location is the URL of the SOAP server to send the request to, and uri is the target namespace of the SOAP service.
However, with the **WSDL mode** the location parameter **may be also** not set in wsdl-schema, and so you **must** pass manually this param with the SoapClient options 
/see [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/soapclient.soapclient.php) for more detail

Comment: @PythonTeam still not work or what's the problem ? if you want I can give you a complete example with WSDL mode

Comment: @regYes still its not working... I can't able to call a method... Plz give some example... Thanks in advance.

Comment: @PythonTeam you want use WSDL mode or non-WSDL ? and if that WSDL mode - you have wsdl scheme(then show this) or you will do a new ?

Comment: then am new to PHP... am trying to write webservice using PHP.

Comment: @PythonTeam I added full example in my answer

Comment: @PythonTeam my pleasure :) if your problem resolved, you can accept this answer for 'close' your question and voteup if my solution was helpful..